# Does it matter where in a unit I put the $R directive to include a resource?

Tags: delphi

Take a look at this little snip:

```
implementation
{$R *.dfm}
```

Do I put my code above `{$R *.dfm}` or below it? Does it matter?
I can't find any confirmation on this question.
Is there a set standard on which to go about this or is it just up the designer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it does not matter but as a rule I put my code below, that compile switch actually links that pas file with a dfm file (pas+dfm = form!), here are some tips.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  ....

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    local_var: String;
    function myFormFunction:String;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  // global vars
  superVar: integer;

const
  // global constants
  MY_CONST = 'TEXT!!!';

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }
// YOUR CODE!
procedure aCoolFunction;
Begin
// your code
    inc(superVar);
End;

function TForm1.myFormFunction: String;
begin
// your code
  local_var := 'some '+ MY_CONST;
  inc(superVar);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Do not teach people how to introduce global variables in every unit. In general, having less of those is a better idea.

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't matter. The code and the resources do not affect each other (unless you try to load a resource that doesn't exist, but that's a completely different issue). Having said that, I prefer to have all options at the top.